# Python import head ache

Tags: python, import

I have the following directory structure:

```
Main.py
A/
    __init__.py
    B/
        __init__.py
        C/
            __init__.py
```

The file `Main.py` contains the code

```
from A import B
from B import C
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty.
When I run `Main.py` I get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ...\Main.py, line 2, in <module>
    from B import C
  ImportError: No module named B
```

What causes this error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When processing `import` statements, Python doesn't look at what you have already imported; it simply looks whether the given module exists in the import path. So you need to write it like this:

```
from A import B
from A.B import C
```